# Finding $P(C)$ with Bayes's Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have two events $C$ and $D$ such that $0<P(D)<1$ and a $P(C|D)=P(C|D^{c}) = \frac{1}{3}$. I am wondering if it is possible to calculate $P(C)$ from only this information.

I've tried using Bayes's theorem, but I haven't been able to solve it yet. Thus, is it not possible to find $P(C)$?

Comment: It is possible, indeed:  $P(C)=\frac 13$.  In general, the so-called Law of Total Probability tell us  that $P(C)=P(C|D)P(D)+P(C|D^c)P(D^c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(C|D)=\frac{P(C\cap D)}{P(D)}=\frac13$$
$$P(C|D^C)=\frac{P(C\cap D^C)}{P(D^C)}=\frac13$$
So
$$P(D)=3P(C\cap D)$$
and
$$P(D^C)=3P(C\cap D^C)$$
Now
$$P(D)+P(D^C)=1$$
Thus,
$$P(C\cap D)+P(C\cap D^C)=\frac13$$
$$P(C)=\frac13$$